# Обнуление значения в $_GET при попытки обновить запись в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Обнуляется значение в ($_GET['id']) при попытки произвести обновление в БД. В запросе ошибок нет проверял, если WHERE ID_Application указать определенное значение то обновление происходит, но при нажатии на кнопку происходит обнуление ($_GET['id']).

```
    <?php
//Отмена
$data1 = $_POST;
    if(isset ($data1['do_no']))
    {
        $result_mail = mysqli_query ($connection,"UPDATE `Application` SET `ID_Status`= '3' WHERE ID_Application =".intval($_GET['id']));
    }       
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST;` .....`$_GET['id']` - ничего не смущает?

Comment: Смущает, только у меня по $_GET['id'] должно обновится определенное значение, как это реализовать?

Comment: а как сам запрос выглядит?на какой урл идут пост?

Comment: <form name ="application_add" id ="application_add" method ="POST" action ="/modify.php">если я так понял.

Comment: Так если у вас POST, почему вы id ищите в GET ?

Comment: у меня на одной страницы формируются ссылки которые принимают id  <a href ="/modify.php?id=<?php echo $object4['ID_Application']; ?>"> при переходе  по ссылки на другую страницу происходит выборка в соответствии с переданным id, и на этой страницы нужно обновить запись в соответствии с переданным id.

Comment: Пробовал так и в переменную $_GET['id'] записать, все данные при нажатии на кнопку  обнуляются:<?php
//Отмена
$data1 = $_POST;
 if(isset ($data1['do_no']))
 {
  $result_mail = mysqli_query ($connection,"UPDATE `Application` SET `ID_Status`= '3' WHERE ID_Application =".$object5['ID_Application']);
 }  
?>

Comment: @viktor.kosolapoff, вам уже 2 человека сказали про POST и GET. POST не умеет передавать данные, которые находятся в URL, потому что по сути это не передача данных, а получение (GET)

Comment: @viktor.kosolapoff, засуньте ваш `id` в hidden поле просто, тогда он через POST отправится.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name ="application_add" id ="application_add" method ="POST" action ="/modify.php?id=ваш_id">
```

Comment: что вы хотите сказать этим кусочком кода?

Comment: То ли это слишком непонятный ответ, то ли вообще не ответ

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я показал пример, как автор может передать одновременно GET и POST данные)